# Changing lists font size re-sizes the whole li

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Im trying to create a header by using html lists but when I try to change the font size to a smaller value it automatically re-sizes the whole li.

[Here is an example of what I mean:](http://jsfiddle.net/Ps2P9/)
Comment out the font size tag to see what I mean...

HTML:

```
<ul id="header">
<li><a><h1>Home</h1></a>
</li>
<li><a><h1>Link2</h1></a>
</li>
<li><a><h1>Link3</h1></a>
</li>
<li><a><h1>Link4</h1></a>
</li>
<li><a><h1>Link5</h1></a>
</li>
<li><a><h1>Link6</h1></a>
</li>
```

Css:

```
#header {
    width: 70em;
    height: 4em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    list-style: none
}

#header li {
    /*font-size: 8pt;*/
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: -3px;
}

    #header a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 9.94em;
    height: 4em;
    background: #FDB813;
}
```

Should I use divs instead or is there another solution?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question correctly but is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Ps2P9/5/

Comment: Well your width and height are in `em` so when you change the font size of the `li` the anchor will inherit the font size and your width and height is affected

Comment: @ayushi Yep thats exactly what I meant... An answer post of that would be great!

Comment: Added. You could accept it by ticking it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add this :

```
#header h1{
    font-size: 8pt;  
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [`em` unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Ems) for setting the width/height of the links.

`em` are relative to the font size, so when you change that you alter their dimensions as well

Answer (score 1):

When you use `display: inline` the size of the element will depend on the text (and the size of the text). There are many ways to change this.

If you want the header to always take up the same width, consider floating the elements and setting a percentage width, depending on the number of elements (5 elements = 20% width).

You can also set the background color on the `#header` element, so that always takes up the same amount of space, but the links change size within it.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a div as the header and then put the ul inside it. You will have more control over styling. To change just the font size on the a tags, add the font-size ; to the #header a {}.

Answer (score 0):

Since the dimensions of the `a` element have been set using the `em` unit, they change when the font size of the element is changed. This also changes the dimensions of the enclosing `li` element, since the `a` element is its only content.

The conclusions depend on what you want. By setting dimensions using the `em` unit, you explicitly want them to depend on the font size. If you do not want that, use some other unit, such as `px` (though this unavoidably raises the question what happens when the font size is increased so that it is larger than the height set in `px` units).

Answer (score 0):

Add a css property

```
#header a{
    font-size: 8pt;  
}
```